# How to embed my latest WordPress post into an external page

Tags: embed

We needed to create three different blogs for the type of website we wanted to make, so we are putting each individual blog on its own subdomain and are building a homepage (which will be the only page on the main website) that connects to all three.

I would like to include an excerpt of the latest post of each blog on the homepage. Only the latest post, switching out each time a new post is made. How could I go about doing this?

Comment: Easiest method would be to use the RSS feed from each site.

Answer (score 0):

You could either build a [WordPress Network](https://wordpress.org/support/article/create-a-network/) which would allow you to manage all the sub domains from within the same site - or you could use the [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) to access and then display the post data from each single WordPress install